# Formatting an integer as octal

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, f#, number-formatting

I'm looking for the format specifier for String.Format() (or if there is a [NumberFormatInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.aspx) class that will do it) to format a integer as octal in .NET, as  `{0:x}` formats it as hex, e.g:

```
String.Format("{0:x}", 15) // returns "f"
```

Comment: Turns out it was available through System.Convert.ToString(15, 8)

Comment: Could you add your result as an answer and accept it?

Comment: Since you've found the answer, you should probably post it *as* an answer. I suspect people are holding off...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`System.Convert.ToString(15, 8)`